# Help identifying " "MessageExtension-Madrid" in ios logs

Tags: ipad, ios

Interested in the following Ios log snippet.  Trying to figuring out what my ever mysterious Ipad is up to.  Couldn't find any leads online.

-My device is not jailbroken and I have no non apple apps installed other than Netflix.

-I do not use Imessage or any other message service on the device.

-All app permissions are set to off

````
 Jan 17 22:40:47 Adams-iPad SpringBoard(UserNotificationsUIKit)[51] <Notice>: Loaded extension com.apple.MobileSMS.MessagesNotificationExtension for categories [ MessageExtension, MessageExtension-AudioRaise, MessageExtension-Madrid, MessageExtension-MadridGroup, MessageExtension-SMS ] with attributes: {
    NSExtensionPointName = "com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension";
    NSExtensionPointVersion = "1.0";
    NSExtensionVersion = "1.0";
    UNNotificationExtensionCategory =     (
        MessageExtension,
        "MessageExtension-AudioRaise",
        "MessageExtension-Madrid",
        "MessageExtension-MadridGroup",
        "MessageExtension-SMS"
    );
    UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden = 1;
    UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio = "0.7";
    UNNotificationExtensionOverridesDefaultTitle = 1;
    UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled = 1;```
````

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that was an interesting little Google detour...

According to [this page](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Messages), 'Madrid' was the codename for the iMessages app when it was still in development, and apparently elements of the internal structure — database names, components, etc — were developed using the code name and have not been changed since.

Now, even if you don't use the Messages app ('Madrid' became 'iMessages' became 'Messages'), Messages is so thoroughly integrated into the OS that some of its components are bound to be invoked. From what you posted it looks like some background daemon is loading a notification extension into the system. That's a bit of code that lurks in the background and posts notifications on the screen if you get text messages. That extension, in turn, is checking in with the Messages app, which is why 'Madrid' is popping up in your logs. This entry seems completely normal to me, so I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  As you can probably see from my previous posts, my initial dive into my ios logs was due to some worry; however, I am now just investigating things out of interest.  I figure if I'm using the device, its worth having at least a cursory knowledge of how it actually operates.  It's amazing how there is simultaneously so much discussion on ios and yet so little clarification.  Thank god for forums.